# QGIS Select Single Feature not correct in attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, select

For some reason, QGIS is not displaying the correct row of my data when I click on a feature with "Select Single Feature" or even the other select tools.

I have a point database linked from mysql.  There is a column named ASR with a unique number.  When I plot all of the points, they are correct - everything is where it should be.  When I label the points they are all correct - ASRs correspond to points in the correct locations.  When I open the attribute table, select a line, and then zoom to that feature, it works fine.  Correct point, correct labeling, all good.

HOWEVER, if I just display the map of all the features and try clicking on one with the 'Show selected only' checked, it doesn't actually select the right point, and moreover it shows the wrong row.  In most cases if I select a rectangle of 20 or 30 points, it actually highlights 20 or 30 OTHER points, and displays various results in the attribute table.

I'm totally confused.  Almost everything is working right and its clear that the record data and point data are correct and in agreement, but selecting features by mouse is totally hosed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Mark. What does the "Show selected only" refer to? The filter "Show selected features" in the attribute table? Are the features highlighted on the map canvas the same rows which are shown in the attribute table? Reading your text, it sounds like you are selecting the features on the map canvas, but the title suggests, that you are dealing with the attribute table.

Comment: I tried to duplicate the problem in QGIS 2.0 in Win7 with a PostgreSQL point data layer. Here the "Show Selected Features" and select on the map canvas seems to work as expected. Could it be a CRS issue? Are you using on-the-fly reprojection?

Comment: Matthias, Micha -  What I meant is that I clicked on Open Attribute Table, which then opened the table in the lower half of the window.  In that window I clicked the box that says "Show Selected Only"   I've done this in many other layers/projects before and had no issues whatsoever, though in each case they were local shapefiles.  In this instance, if I click on one of the points a row is indeed displayed in the attribute table, but it isn't the right row.  If, however, I unclick "show selected only" and highlight a random row, then zoom to that row, the correct point is displayed.